# How do you get the angle of the lid from the CLI?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, command-line, hardware

I understand the following command can be used to determine if the laptop lid is open or closed:

`ioreg -r -k AppleClamshellState -d 4 | grep AppleClamshellState`.

My question is, when the lid is open, how can I ascertain its angle relative to the surface it's resting on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no *easy* way to do this from within the computer (you could always measure it of course). The hardware on laptops only needs to know whether the lid is closed or not, so a simple on/off switch is enough and built-in.

---

There are (at least) two threads on reddit where apparently the tilt level seems to control audio volume:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/6fek1m/hope_you_dont_mind_having_the_volume_turned_up/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/6fowct/lid_controlled_volume_mac_edition/

The first one is quite obviously a fake, the second one claims

> You're right! I used the ambient light sensor values to calculate the percentage

So while there isn't a way to get the angle directly, it can be calculated/approximated using other sensors.

Comment: I think you're ignoring the opportunity to superglue a Bluetooth spirit level to the lid of the MacBook :-)  Oh, and one to the chassis too.